# Nodejs error encoding when get external site's content

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request

I used `get` method of `request` module to get content of external site. If encoding of external site is utf-8, it is ok, but it has display error with other encodings such as shift-jis

```
function getExternalUrl(request, response, url){

    mod_request.get(url, function (err, res, body) {
    //mod_request.get({uri: url, encoding: 'binary'}, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err){
            console.log("\terr=" + err);
        }else{
            var result = res.body;
            // Process res.body
            response.write(result);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}
```

How can I get content of external site with correct encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do:

1. Get with `binary` encoding

   var mod_request = require('request');
   mod_request.get({ uri: url, encoding: 'binary', headers: headers }, function(err, res, body) {});
2. Create a `Buffer` with `binary` format

   var contentBuffer = new Buffer(res.body, 'binary');
3. Get real encoding of page by `detect-character-encoding` npm

   var mod_detect_character_encoding = require('detect-character-encoding');
   var charsetMatch = mod_detect_character_encoding(contentBuffer);
4. Convert page to `utf-8` by `iconv` npm

   var mod_iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
   var iconv = new mod_iconv(charsetMatch.encoding, 'utf-8');
   var result = iconv.convert(contentBuffer).toString();

P/S: `This way is only applied for text file (html, css, js). Please do not apply for image file or others which is not text`